# Scientia fellowships - Marie Skłodowska-Curie status and reputation?

Tags: postdocs, funding, marie-curie

I recently found out about the [University of Oslo Scientia fellowship program](https://www.med.uio.no/english/research/scientia-fellows/). The program seems to have (at least some of) its funding from the Marie Skłodowska Curie foundation and it says [here](https://www.med.uio.no/english/research/scientia-fellows/apply/) that fellows have a "Marie Skłodowska-Curie status – a quality stamp for your CV".

My questions:

1. Is this program similar (in terms of its standing) to the Marie Curie individual fellowship?
2. Are applications evaluated along with other (Marie Curie) applications or only the Scientia ones are evaluated (perhaps then it has a lower competition rate?)
3. The above link says 2019-2024...would that mean that a new fellow in 2022 would only have two years of funding?

Related questions:
[Why is the Marie Curie Individual Fellowship only for 'experienced researchers'?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/140971/why-is-the-marie-curie-individual-fellowship-only-for-experienced-researchers)

Comment: Probably only the University of Oslo can answer 2 or 3. As for 1, try and get in touch with previous Scientia fellows and see what their CV looks like now.

Comment: I can't find any sign it is an ITN.  https://ec.europa.eu/programmes/horizon2020/en/h2020-section/marie-sklodowska-curie-actions

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist it is a COFUND program.

Comment: Here is the cordis entry: https://cordis.europa.eu/project/id/801133

Comment: Well, that's the answer then.  It has the status of a COFUND.  Not quite the same as an individual fellowship.